# How to define url X-AMZ-Expires in Shrine configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, shrine

When we call the method `url` the value for `X-AMZ-Expires` can be defined with the argument `expires_in`.

Is there a way to define this on Shrine's configuration file or in the uploader so that every time I call `url` I wouldn't need to give the value of `expired_in`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do it via the `url_options` plugin:

```
Shrine.plugin :url_options, store: { expires_in: 60*60 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding to the above answer: This has changed recently to default_url_options:

```
Shrine.plugin :default_url_options, store: { expires_in: 60*60 }
```

Comment: In Shrine 3, the `default_url_options` plugin has been renamed to just `url_options`.